# How scroll absolute div?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I need to scroll div absolute without moving the body. I want the same effect as on https://www.pinterest.com. Does anyone know how to achieve it?

Like so:
[image]

Comment: In the future, please include code that you have already tried. Lack of code is probably the reason you've been downvoted so many times.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want something like this [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwTJD/), here is the code:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += '<p>hlllo</p>';
}
```

#### CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    position:fixed;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Osteospermum_Flower_Power_Spider_Purple_2134px.jpg);
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
}

#content {  
    width:500px;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#content p {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to do it. Using Javascript or CSS (CSS3 to be exact). For Javascript you could use a Parallax effect (Stellar.js or Skrollr or ...). Or you could use simply css properties  by adding a background-image and this background-image will have a small transition that makes it looks scrolling. You could check the css of Pinterest for that.

Comment: On Pinterest after open frame they add class "no-scroll"  to body.I understand this part ,but I can't imagine  how body scroll transition to absulute div scroll?